# SQL Script select last column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7NeV.png)

I want to select last

Comment: please take a look at this link to see how you can improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: very well thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should give data in text not in image. Anyways
Try this:

```
select *
from data_table
qualify() row_number()over(partition by computerName order by timestamp desc)=1
```

or this:

```
select *
from data_table
where (computerName,timestamp)
in 
(select computerName,max(timestamp)
from data_table
group by 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Partition By**:

```
SELECT 
    ComputerName,
    CodeNumber,
    TimeStamp 
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        ComputerName,
        CodeNumber,
        TimeStamp,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ComputerName ORDER BY t.TimeStamp DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM @data t
) AS [sub]
where [sub].[Rank] = 1
```