# SQL Server : select only last record per customer from a join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have these 3 tables :

[image: Customer type 1]

[image: Customer type 2]

[image]

The first 2 tables define customers of different types ,i.e second table has other columns which are not included in table 1 i just left them the same to save complexity.

The third table defines orders for both types of customers . Each customer has more than one orders

I want to select the last order for every customer, i.e the order with `order_id` 4 for `customer` 1 which was created on 23/12/2016 and the order with `order_id` 5 for `customer` 2 which was created on 26/12/2016

I tried something like this :

```
select * 
from customertype1 
left join order on order.customer_id = customertype1.customer_id 
order by order_id desc;
```

But this gives me multiple records for every customer, as I have stated above I want only the last order for every `customertype1`.

Comment: you can use CROSS APPLY and SELECT TOP 1 ...ORDER BY DateCreated DESC inside the CROSS APPLY query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the last order for each customer, then you only need the `orders` table:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by datecreated desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to include all customers, then you need to combine the two tables.  Assuming they are mutually exclusive:

```
with c as (
      select customer_id from customers1 union all
      select customer_id from customers2
     )
select o.*
from c left join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by datecreated desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     on c.customer_id = o.customer_id and seqnum = 1;
```

A note about your data structure:  You should have one table for *all* customers.  You can then define a foreign key constraint between `orders` and `customers`.  For the additional columns, you can have additional tables for the different types of customers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY`.

- `ROW_NUMBER()`: it will give sequence no to your each row
- `PARTITION BY`: it will group your data by given column

When you use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` both together then first partition by group your records and then row_number give then sequence no by each group, so for each group you have start sequence from 1

Help Link: [Example of ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486559/6606630)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea.  You can work out the details.

```
with customers as
(select customer_id, customer_name
from table1
union
select customer_id, customer_name
from table2)

, lastOrder as
(select customer_id, max(order_id) maxOrderId
 from orders
 group by customer_id)

select *
from lastOrder join customers on lastOrder.Customer_id = customers.customer_id
 join orders on order_id = maxOrderId
```